# Custom label elements associated to form controls via ElementInternals?

Tags: forms, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, lit-element

I'm writing a custom input element called `fancy-input`, which can participate in a form via the `FormInternals` API. In particular, the `ElementInternals.labels` property gives me a list of the `label` elements associated, via their `for` attributes, to an instance of `fancy-input`.

But now let's say I also want to write a custom *label* element called `fancy-label`. It renders a native label element in its shadow DOM with fancy styles, formatting, etc.  How do make it known that an instance of `fancy-label` is the "label" associated with an instance of `fancy-input`. In particular, I'd like my `fancy-label` node appear in the `NodeList` returned by calling `ElementInternals.labels` on the associated `fancy-input` element.

One possible approach would be for `fancy-label` to render a native `label` into a slot, keeping it in the light DOM and, hence, visible to the form and the `fancy-input` element. But is there a solution with the native `label` in the shadow DOM of `fancy-label`?